# How can i call service manager in my view?

Tags: zend-framework2, helper, service-management

I use ZF2... How can call service manager in a viewhelper?
My probem is that. I use slug module for sef link. 
( link : https://packagist.org/packages/olliebrennan/zf2-slug-generator )

And i need to call it's service from a view helper. But how can do this?

```
class CommonHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function getSefLink($link){
        //my problem is here, how can i call service locator??
        $slug = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SeoUrl\Slug');
        return $slug->create($link);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 Service in View Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941432/zend-framework-2-service-in-view-helper/20943581#20943581)

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator();
```